# How to push route onClick in list React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is the list which I am trying to display

```
<li key={data.url} onClick={this.props.history.push('/viewnetworkaccount')}>
      {data.keyName}
</li>
```

I want to push data.url. How To do so.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way,

```
<li key={data.url} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/viewnetworkaccount')}>
     {data.keyName}
</li>
```

Also make sure you wrap your component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC.